# How to test functions present in the drool file without calling rule?

Tags: java, junit, drools, rule-engine, jboss-rules

I want to do junit for my rule files. My rule file broadly has two things:

1. a rule
2. a helper function (in drools, not Java) which I am calling from ***then*** section of a rule

Now I want to test(assert) this ***function*** isolatedly based on the test case. is there any way possible to do this?

```
function void print(String string){
            System.out.println(string);
            return true;
 }

rule "XXYJK"
dialect "mvel"
salience 10
when
 objofTheclass : exampleClass() eval
 (
  objofTheclass.isKeyMatched("XXYJK")

 )
then
print("XXYJK");
end
```

Now I can call this rule from java code like this way.

```
statelessSession.setAgendaFilter(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter("XXYJK"));
```

`statelessSession.executeWithResults(rulesEngineParameters);`

Now I want to do similar things without calling the rule itself or executing the whole drl file . Only the print() function I want to call.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to unit test your function in the rule, I'd suggest moving it to a static method in a separate class file. You can easily unit test that.

e.g. class with print as static method

```
package my.package
public class MyFunctions {
    public static void print(String string){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

You can then import the static method as a function in your rule by replacing your function definition with an import statement:

```
import function my.package.MyFunctions.print
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I am more interested to find out whether I can access the function from the drool file itself or not.  I saw some post of accessing via Kie api but cant able to use in our project. We are using drool 5.6+ version where it is not supported. Also I was trying to generate dynamic rule so that I can append this function and test it .

Comment: This is a nice solution to involve even in a project with Spock/Groovy testing:  I am continuing to test the `.drl` rules themselves in Spock, while I can refactor `.drl` helper functions to instead be Java static methods like here, and be able to test them in JUnit (without needing to test them via the rules [in my Spock testing]).  The new Java static helpers are called from the rules, refactoring calls that used to be to `.drl` functions.